# Plural-active, singular-active or another voice when writing a paper by yourself?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

I'm working on a draft paper which will likely have no coauthors. I'm wondering how to phrase my paper, and the abstract especially, in terms of voice. Which of the following should I prefer?

- "We present XYZ ..."
- "This paper/this work presents XYZ ..."
- "I present XYZ ..."

The former sounds a bit too "royal", the second is the passive voice which I tend to avoid, and the third seems overly presumptuous.

What should I go for? Or - am I missing a fourth option?

**Note:** In case it matters, the paper is in some branch of applied Computer Science.